# How to retrieve parser context while deserializing JSON with Jackson and @JSonPOJOBuilder

Tags: java, json, jackson

The question: is it possible somehow to retrieve the json parser from withing POJO objects and/or POJOcreators (for reporting/debugging purposes) without writing a complete custom deserializer?

Let me explain in the example. Currently I'm deserializing JSON using [@JSonPOJOBuilder](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonPOJOBuilder.html) and mixins:

```
public interface Custom {
  ...
}

protected class CustomImpl implements Custom {
  CustomImpl(String prop1, Integer prop2,...) {}
  ...
}

@JsonDeserialize(builder=CustomBuilder.class)
public abstract class CustomMixIn {
  public CustomMixIn(
    JsonProperty("prop1") String prop1,
    JsonProperty("prop2") Integer prop2,
    ...
  ) {}
}

@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName="build")
public class CustomBuilder {
  public String prop1;
  public Integer prop2
  ...
  public Custom build() {
    // validate fields, perform other prerequisite actions
    return new CustomImpl(prop1, prop2,...);
  }
}

...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Custom.class, CustomMixIn.class);
```

As one may see everything is pretty straightforward and it actually *works*. However I would like to have a reference to the currently active parser from within CustomBuilder.build() method to be able to correctly report of problems/features of the data being loaded. Throwing an exception isn't suitable because those things I'd like to report aren't errors, just "some specific properties" of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the standard Jackson 'builder' deserializer and inject the json parser instance into the builder bean. The custom deserializer can be set via using [the deserializer modifier feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.java).

I cannot say that it looks very elegant though. That is because the `BuilderBasedDeserializer.finishBuild(...)` method is unfortunately final which makes it practically impossible to inject the json parser in other way then showed in the example. Passing it as a constructor or build method parameter would look nicer.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonBuilder {
    public static final String JSON = "{\"field\":\"value\"}";

    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Builder.class)
    public static class Bean {
        public final String field;

        public Bean(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean{" +
                    "field='" + field + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static interface JsonParserAware {
        void withJsonParser(JsonParser parser);
    }

    static class Builder implements JsonParserAware {
        public String field;

        private JsonParser parser;

        @Override
        public void withJsonParser(JsonParser parser) {
            this.parser = parser;
        }

        public Bean build() {
            System.out.println(parser);
            return new Bean(field + "(build by builder)");
        }
    }

    private static class MyBuilderDeserializer extends BuilderBasedDeserializer {

        protected MyBuilderDeserializer(BuilderBasedDeserializer src) {
            super(src);
            _vanillaProcessing = false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object deserializeFromObject(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            Object object = super.deserializeFromObject(jp, ctxt);
            if (object instanceof JsonParserAware) {
                ((JsonParserAware) object).withJsonParser(jp);
            }
            return object;
        }
    }

    private static class BuilderBeanDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {
        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(
                DeserializationConfig config,
                BeanDescription beanDesc,
                JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
            if (deserializer instanceof BuilderBasedDeserializer) {
                return new MyBuilderDeserializer((BuilderBasedDeserializer) deserializer);
            }
            return super.modifyDeserializer(config, beanDesc, deserializer);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BuilderBeanDeserializerModifier());
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Bean.class));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Parser: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser@6be46e8f
Bean{field='value(build by builder)'}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recipe! It looks pretty tough, however it seems it's better than all my own attempts to solve the problem. I wonder why Jackson authors use `final` so often.